# Can't see how this equation simplifies

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I can't identify how line 1 has simplified to line 2 in this equation. I've been staring at this for quite a while, but nothing has come to me yet. I think it's just the numerator that is confusing me, since the denominator's powers cancel nicely. I think they have divided by 3 and multiplied by something similar to $2(5x+3)^{-1}$. I just can't see what!

[image: How did they get from line 1 to line 2?]

Can anyone give me any hints? Many thanks!

Comment: If you expand the parentheses in the second line using the distributive law, what do you get?

Comment: Ah thank you! They have taken a factor of $3(5x+3)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ out! Right?

Comment: Right. (filler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have taken a factor of $3(5x+3)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ out of the numerator, and simplified the denominator.

If you find yourself at a situation like line 1, think to yourself:

- What can be simplified in the numerator and/or denominator?
- What is common to the numerator & denominator?
- What factors can I take out from numerator?